# how should I extract the protocl of the current request uri in php

Tags: php

I don't know how should I get the current request protocol in PHP. I haven't found any straight `$_SERVER` key for this. I don't want a straight string split out of current request.

For instance:

```
http://localhost/someDomain
```

then:

```
echo $_SERVER["protocl"];

// http
```

What should be done?

Comment: i don't know why people down vote down vote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"];
```

is what you're looking for (please pay attetion, this will also return protocol version)

A workaround could be something like

```
$protocol_version = $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"];
$protocol = strpos($protocol_version, 'HTTPS') === false ? 'http' : 'https';
```

or (more general solution)

```
$protocol = explode('/',$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"])[0]; //!! valid only in php > 5.3 !!
$protocol_array = explode('/',$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]);
$protocol = $protocol_array[0];
```